# How do I create a exception for a subdirectoy so the main HTacces won't interfere with subdirectory?

Tags: .htaccess, subdirectory

Well I have a main website which runs ELGG1.8 and it needs it's own created htaccess to function properly. But now I want to create a subdirectory in my main folder and the main /htaccess is messing it up, I cannot acces the folder, just run html files, no php, nothing..

How can I edit this .htaccess to make an exception?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on

# If Elgg is in a subdirectory on your site, you might need to add a RewriteBase line
# containing the path from your site root to elgg's root. e.g. If your site is
# http://example.com/ and Elgg is in http://example.com/sites/elgg/, you might need
#
#RewriteBase /sites/elgg/
#
# here, only without the # in front.
#
# If you're not running Elgg in a subdirectory on your site, but still getting lots
# of 404 errors beyond the front page, you could instead try:
#
#RewriteBase /

# In for backwards compatibility
RewriteRule ^pg\/([A-Za-z0-9\_\-]+)$ engine/handlers/page_handler.php?handler=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^pg\/([A-Za-z0-9\_\-]+)\/(.*)$ engine/handlers/page_handler.php?handler=$1&page=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^tag\/(.+)\/?$ engine/handlers/page_handler.php?handler=search&page=$1


RewriteRule ^action\/([A-Za-z0-9\_\-\/]+)$ engine/handlers/action_handler.php?action=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^cache\/(.*)$ engine/handlers/cache_handler.php?request=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^services\/api\/([A-Za-z0-9\_\-]+)\/(.*)$ engine/handlers/service_handler.php?handler=$1&request=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^export\/([A-Za-z]+)\/([0-9]+)\/?$ engine/handlers/export_handler.php?view=$1&guid=$2
RewriteRule ^export\/([A-Za-z]+)\/([0-9]+)\/([A-Za-z]+)\/([A-Za-z0-9\_]+)\/$ engine/handlers/export_handler.php?view=$1&guid=$2&type=$3&idname=$4

RewriteRule xml-rpc.php engine/handlers/xml-rpc_handler.php
RewriteRule mt/mt-xmlrpc.cgi engine/handlers/xml-rpc_handler.php


# rule for rewrite module test during install - can be removed after installation
RewriteRule ^rewrite.php$ install.php

# Everything else that isn't a file gets routed through the page handler
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\_\-]+)$ engine/handlers/page_handler.php?handler=$1 [QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\_\-]+)\/(.*)$ engine/handlers/page_handler.php?handler=$1&page=$2 [QSA]


</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right underneath the `RewriteEngine on`, in your htaccess file, add this rule to allow requests for the directory to pass-through:

```
RewriteRule ^directory/to/pass/through - [L]
```

This makes it so when someone requests `http://your.domain.com/directory/to/pass/through`, the rewrite engine will let that through without interferring with it.